# web service for retriving all recoord where having same value

Tags: php, json

```
define('HOST','*****');
define('USER','*****');
define('PASS','*****');
define('DB','*****');

$con = mysqli_connect(HOST,USER,PASS,DB) or die('Unable to Connect');
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='GET') {
    $user  = $_GET['user'];
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM sample WHERE user='".$user."'";
    $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $output[]=$row;
    }


print(json_encode($output));
mysqli_close($con);
```

This is my php code it return only single record which match the value. But i want return all record which match to given value.

Comment: sql injection aside, the code should does what you want.

Comment: **Never** pass raw strings in your SQL queries. **Always** use a sanitization function like [`mysqli_real_escape_string`](http://php.net/manual/fr/mysqli.real-escape-string.php). [Read about SQL injections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).